# Excel VBA extend table when data added below table

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table in Excel that when users add data after the table, the data doesn't belong to the table.

I've created a code that can be executed to extend the table. The code is as follows:

```
Sub ExtendTableToLastRow()

    Sheets("Update").Select
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    'LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Offset(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TUpdate").Resize Range("$A$2:$AK$" & LastRow)
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

The problem is this has to be executed manually.

Based on the comments I've created the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Sizes the table to include all new rows
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Offset(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TUpdate").Resize Range("$A$2:$AK$" & LastRow)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

But the code executes when I add a value in a cell under the table, but now when I copy a row.

Comment: You could put that code in `Worksheet_Change` event and just check that the changed cells are actually new additions to the table and not some other cells on the sheet.

Comment: when addint worksheet_change the code it is only executed when a cell is upated, but now when I copy new rows

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` will definitely fire if you copy a row into the sheet that has the event handler. With `Worksheet_Change`, you can use `Me` instead of `ActiveSheet` to ensure that the correct `Range` reference is being used.

Comment: It works with Me except that this line -> If Me.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

Comment: Use `If Me.FilterMode Then Me.AutoFilter.ShowAllData` - just use `Me` for `ActiveSheet` everywhere in the event handler.

Comment: I missed that. Thanks

Comment: You can make Excel do that : `Application.AutoCorrect.AutoExpandListRange = True` run this line only one time to change Excel settings.

Comment: @Fadi - maybe you should post that tip as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your code as a handler for the Worksheet_Change event.

[Arrtice on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx)

Comment: Actually, the code gets fired when I enter a value in a cell under the table, but not when I copy some rows. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 3):

You can change Excel setting to do that :

`File > Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect Options > AutoFormat As You Type` and check `Include new rows and columns in table`

Or run this line only one time:

```
Application.AutoCorrect.AutoExpandListRange = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I believe this should help!

good luck .

http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/0101%20Create%20a%20self%20adjusting%20range.htm